# Get array key from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So this callback function works fine and all but I am trying to get the key string for each array within my object that is subject to the .map function (see data below).

My JSON object has the structure of:

```
data = object->
         users: Array [3]
            0: joe
            1: mike
            2: jon
         friends: Array[2]
            0: steve
            1: peter
```

I would like to be able to print out 'users' and 'friends' and store them in the language property of the object.

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    response($.map(data, function (item) {
        var array = item;
        var entities = [];
        if (array.length > 0) {
            entities.push({ header: true, language: array }); //my feeble attempt, which print out [object, object] of course
        }
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var entity = array[i];
            entities.push({
                label: entity.name,
                value: entity.name,
                link: entity.link
            });
        }
        return entities;
    }));
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample expected result?

Comment: I have a feeling this might be an XY problem. Given the data structure you posted above, what is your ultimate goal? How are you trying to transform it (and what are you trying to do along the way)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `$` refers to jQuery.

So for `$.map`, if the first argument is an object, then the callback function can receive two arguments: the property and the key string.

To obtain the key string, you just need to add a second parameter:

```
response($.map(data, function (item, key) {
    console.log(key)
}));
```

Then you will see `users` and `friends` printed.

Likewise, you could get array index with the second parameter, if the first argument to `$.map` is an array

See jQuery doc for details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: Thanks so much. I read that doc but was expecting a more complex solution so I glossed over that. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @ambe5960 just read the doc more carefully next time :D it's really well documented.